# Firestore Error

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am moving to using Firestore on my Android app (from Firebase real-time database). I have encountered an issue which I have a hard time to pinpoint.
This is the error from logcat:

```
07-14 20:42:32.565 13093-13093/com.aayaffe.sailingracecoursemanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.aayaffe.sailingracecoursemanager, PID: 13093
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza.zzb(SourceFile:324)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzd.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher
        at com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(Splitter.java:119)
        at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.<clinit>(GrpcUtil.java:200)
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.<clinit>(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:81)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.forTarget(OkHttpChannelBuilder.java:137)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:48)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:27)
        at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:70)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.zzd.<init>(SourceFile:88)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.zzf.zza(SourceFile:1217)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.zzh.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza$zza.run(SourceFile:190)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The issue apparently happens when trying to read from the DB, but I am not sure of that.

I have discovered one thing.
The issue happens on an Android version 6.0.1 but not on an Android version 8.0.0

The libraries used:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
implementation 'com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker:library:1.9'
implementation 'com.tenmiles:helpstack:1.2.0'
implementation 'io.doorbell:android-sdk:0.2.8@aar'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
```

Comment: Also share the code of the activity where you are encountering an error.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the versions of the relevant libraries.

Comment: @DougStevenson done

Comment: try adding guava as library in your project:    api 'com.google.guava:guava:25.1-android'

Comment: CharMatcher is part of guava.  Firestore depends on version 20.0, but you're pulling in 22.0.  I don't know if this is the problem, but try backing your requirement of guava down to 20.0.  (see the output of `./gradlew :app:dependencies`)

Comment: @DougStevenson That was it!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @DougStevenson this is the answer:

CharMatcher is part of guava. Firestore depends on version 20.0, but you're pulling in 22.0.

Backing the requirement of guava down to 20.0. (also see the output of ./gradlew :app:dependencies)

Comment: To generalise; if you are importing guava in your gradle build file yourself, make sure that the version you import is one that is compatible (the same version) as the one Firebase uses. This Answer saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

**Clear the data in the application manager on the device.**

**Then run the app again.**

Hope it helps!

Comment: That did not work. Besides, how can that be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, please add the following lines of code to progauard rule:

```
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```